# Converting shapefile to .osm.pbf

Tags: python, shapefile, openstreetmap

I am trying to convert a GIS LINE shapefile into a .osm.pbf file on Windows.

I've done some research on the topic and some tools that kept coming out are:

- Merkaator
- shp2osm - which deals mostly with point shapefile
- shape2osm.py - which keeps bringing up an error with importing * elementtree.SimpleXMLWriter

But nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 7):

According to https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles you can try JOSM with the OpenData plugin to open a Shapefile.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software_comparison/Import_a_shapefile#Advanced:_Conversion_tools lists various other tools for converting a shapefile to OSM data:

> There are multiple tools for converting shapefiles into .osm format
>   suitable for importing. These include:
>
> - Merkaartor — simply import the shp, export the osm.xml.
> - shp2osm (and polyshp2osm) — require some programming skill, but very flexible
> - shp-to-osm.jar — less flexible, but requires only a simple configuration file
> - shape2osm — a Python script that will convert a POINT shapefile to OSM XML
> - PostGIS
>
>   - convert shp to osm using grass and gpsbabel
>   - Load the shapefile into PostGIS first, using shp2pgsql (feature of PostGIS) May be helpful as first conversion step
> - ogr2osm (ogr2osm) — a new script to convert any OGR supported vector format into .osm format, with emphasis in converting polygon
>     boundaries into relations
> - Using QGIS & GPX Editor to convert to GPX
>
>   - 1) Menu "Plugins/ Manage Plugins..." enable ,,GPS Tools".
>   - 2) Menu "Plugins/GPS Tools/Create new GPS layer"
>   - 3) Select feature(s) in the default layer. Copy, paste into a GPS tracks layer, save the changed layer.
>   - 4) In GPX Editor open the gpx file. Menu "Edit/ OpenStreetMap Tools/ Anonymize time".
> - MapCreator-Toolset: ShapeToOsmTool — This C#-OpenSource tool converts a set of shape files to an osm file, applying specific
>     conversion rules defined in a dedicated XML conversion rule file.
>
>   - The tool is simple and flexible.
>   - The tool can convert many layers (represented by many shape files) to one OSM output file.
>   - The tool supports the following geometries: Polygon, LineString and Point. A Polygon will be mapped to a Closed OSM Way, a LineString
>       to a OSM Way and a Point to a OSM Node.
>   - With certain limits the tool can convert geometry types (Polygon to Point, LineString to Point), if so wanted.
>   - The tool supports a flexible Tag generation. The Tag values can be constant or read out of the shape file fields.
> - SHPtoOSMBoundaries python script. If the SHP contains Administrative Boundaries and you want to transform them into OSM in
>     order to autogenerate and join the multiple boundary relations before
>     importing.

Please don't forget that you are not allowed to import a shapefile directly into OSM! See the [Import Guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the problem and solved using JOSM and two different plugins:

JOSM -> https://josm.openstreetmap.de/

OpenData -> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/OpenData

PBF -> https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM/Plugins/PBF

With this three pices you will be able to convert a .shp file into a .osm.pbf (and probably others formats).

Comment: Did you ever try ogr2ogr?

Comment: Could you elaborate?